# Поставить условие if c#

Tags: c#

Есть таблица (Sql Server), в нём несколько строк.  Если я добавлю в таблицу ещё одну строку, как поставить условие `if (добавилась строка)`?

```js
static void Main(string[] args) {
    using(SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT s.id as shedule_id, s.name_ru as shedule_name_ru, s.sendType as shedule_sendType, c1.cod as typsendtype , s.typPeriod, c2.cod as time_name_ru, s.metaAlg, m.cod as meta_cod, s.dt_send, s.dt_beg as shedule_dt_beg, s.dt_send_daytime as shedule_dt_send_daytime, s.dt_period_end  as shedule_dt_period_end , s.dt_upd as shedule_dt_upd, s.dt_create as shedule_dt_crt FROM Shedule s  inner join ClBaseItem c1 on s.sendType=c1.id inner join ClBaseItem c2 on s.typPeriod=c2.id inner join MetaAlg m on s.metaAlg=m.id", cn))

    using(DataTable dt = new DataTable()) {
      adapter.Fill(dt);
      if () // тут надо поставить условие        
        MyTimer NewTimerRecord = new MyTimer();
      NewTimerRecord.Enabled = true;
      NewTimerRecord.Interval = 300000;
      NewTimerRecord.Elapsed += RecordTime;
      NewTimerRecord.AutoReset = true;

    }

    static void RecordTime(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e) {
      ((MyTimer) sender).Stop();
      var s_id = ((MyTimer) sender).s_id.ToString();
      var alg = ((MyTimer) sender).alg.ToString();
      var date = DateTime.Now;

      string sql = string.Format("Insert Into Alg_stack" +
        "(shedule_id,metaAlg,datetime) Values( @s_id,@alg, @date)");

      using(SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection()) {
        cn.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=192.168.1.156;Initial Catalog=ihd_aktobe;User ID=sa;Password=Pa$$w0rd";
        cn.Open();
        using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cn)) {

          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@s_id", s_id);
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@alg", alg);
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", date);
          cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        cn.Close();

      }
    }
```

Comment: вопрос точно про c#? все зависит от того **как** добавляется строка.

Comment: @Grundy строка добавляется в ручную

Comment: Добавьте весь необходимый код в вопрос

Comment: @Grundy обновил вопрос

Comment: [SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery: Выполняет инструкцию Transact-SQL для установленного соединения и **возвращает количество задействованных в инструкции строк**.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: хотя судя по предоставленному коду - никак

Comment: @Grundy вообще можно так сделать? Если да, то покажите простой пример! Потом я сам доделаю.Спасибо!

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41404/discussion-between-grundy-and-propro17).

Answer (score 1):

На уровне Sql Server тригером на вставку. В следующем примере указанному пользователю (MaryM) по электронной почте отправляется сообщение при изменении таблицы Customer

```
    IF OBJECT_ID ('Sales.reminder2','TR') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TRIGGER Sales.reminder2;
GO
CREATE TRIGGER reminder2
ON Sales.Customer
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE 
AS
   EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
        @profile_name = 'AdventureWorks2012 Administrator',
        @recipients = 'danw@Adventure-Works.com',
        @body = 'Don''t forget to print a report for the sales force.',
        @subject = 'Reminder';
GO
```

---

Либо после вставки еще раз бросай запрос что б обновить набор данных